# Vertical scroll bar has wrong size after device rotation

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have a function where I make a UIScrollView and one more function for resizing UIView if InterfaceOrientation did change, but after rotating my vertical scroll bar has 1/3 the size of the width of my ScrollView.

```
wrapper.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                           cover_h + thumb_border*2,
                           startView.frame.size.width,
                           startView.frame.size.height-(cover_h+thumb_border*3));

wrapper.contentSize = CGSizeMake((int)thumb_w*2+thumb_border-1,(int) thumb_h*(slice/2)+thumb_border*((slice-1)/2));
wrapper.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, thumb_border, 0, thumb_border);
```

Code of formating ScrollView in init and resize is this same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the way you are resizing it is using the 'thumb' variables (_w, _h, _border). Are these being reset after the view is rotated? If they are set up to position everything correctly say for portrait view, when you switch to landscape view the sizes will all be wrong won't they? You might have to change those variables?

Comment: yes, i did refresh sizes with new self.view[ width, height] parameters and i did resize after rotate, in willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation

Comment: If you rescale the view in willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation, this happens before the new view is created I think. Try doing it in didAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation or a similar function